# trouble setting selected option / .attr("selected",true)

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I am creating an select like this:

```
<select id="teamNameLabel" data-corners="false" onchange="GetSelectedTeam()" data-bind="options: teams, optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'id'">
    <option value="1">Select a Team...</option>
</select>
```

My application is a single page, so when an option is selected it is assigned to TeamId like this:

```
TeamId = $('#teamNameLabel').val();
```

I would like the selected option to be what was last selected when you navigate back to this page.  I tested it with this when the page loaded, but the alert keeps coming back as `undefined`.

```
$("#teamNamelabel option").eq(TeamId+1).attr("selected","selected");
alert($("teamNameLabel option:selected").val());
```

Is there anyway i can set the selectedOption or .attr(selected) to be TeamId?

Comment: although `.attr()` should work, `.prop` would be the "correct" way to change the selected **property**. `.prop("selected",true);`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are missing `#` in that selector inside your alert and also you can just

```
alert($("#teamNameLabel").val());
```

instead of

```
alert($("#teamNameLabel option:selected").val());
```

And to set the value.. simply use `.val` again like below,

```
$("#teamNameLabel").val(TeamId);
```

You can use `.eq` selector when you need to select an option without knowing its value.

Assume you want to select 3rd option, then

```
//             3rd option = 2 because .eq takes index
$("#teamNamelabel option").eq(2).prop("selected", true);
```